# Automatically insert data into a table from another table and combine values with same id

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress website. In the MySql database, I have two tables. Table 1 is automatically updated when a user submits a certain form on my website. Table 2 is one that I created myself, and currently isn't linked to anything.

As you can see in Table 1, each time a user submits a form, the values in each submission are entered over multiple rows with the same submission_id.

Notice the values in the "key" column in Table 1 correspond to the column headings in Table 2. I created Table 2 so that when data is entered in Table 1, all the values are listed in their own columns and are on one row in Table 2.

QUESTION: How do I automatically update Table 2, with values found in Table 1 when a user makes a new submission, and combine all the values with the same submission_id on one row in Table 2?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EZ1f.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKUNg.png]

Comment: *I created Table 2 so that when data is entered in Table 1, all the values are listed in their own columns and are on one row in Table 2.* What is the reason? create a view.

Comment: @Akina. Ok, I will post the table-formatted text versions.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Possibly. But I don't know how to write the SQL to solve the problem.